# Making Amazon Web Services S3 POST request in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, amazon-web-services, http-post, nsurlrequest

I am trying to use AWS S3 service to host images of my iOS application in Swift language.
At this step I am just trying to simply post png image with POST request. 
In any POST request for AWS S3 we need to make an authorization header which consists of the information that authenticate this request. To encode data with HMAC SHA256 which is required by Amazon I use GitHub project as my Subproject from this link: https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift
This helped me to encrypt the signature however when I tried to send this request I received an error which says: "SignatureDoesNotMatchThe request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method."

Here is my code:

```
        var img = UIImage(named: "myImage.png")
        var imageData : NSData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 1.0)

        let key = "mybucketname"

        let url = NSURL(string:"http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/")
        var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)         
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        let uniqueId = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().globallyUniqueString
        var postBody:NSMutableData = NSMutableData()
        var boundary:String = "------WebKitFormBoundary\(uniqueId)"
        request.addValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Type")
//      I am trying to generate a date stamp compatible for request 
        let date = NSDate()
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.timeStyle = .ShortStyle
        formatter.stringFromDate(date)

        var dateKey = ["AWS4"+"My AWSSecretKey","20150317"]
//      Here is the signature that I'm trying to make
        var signature = "My AWSSecretKey".sha256()?.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions())
        request.addValue("AWS MYAWSACCESSKEYID:\(signature)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        request.addValue("Wed, 18 Mar 2015 20:39:27 +0000", forHTTPHeaderField: "Date")
        request.addValue(key, forHTTPHeaderField:"key")
        request.addValue("\(postBody.length)", forHTTPHeaderField:"Content-Length")


        postBody.appendData("--\(boundary)\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        postBody.appendData("Content-Type: image/png\r\n".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        postBody.appendData(imageData)
        var postData = String()
        postData += "\r\n"
        postData += "\r\n--\(boundary)--\r\n"
        postBody.appendData(postData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        request.HTTPBody = postBody

        var error: NSError?
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, err) -> Void in
            var stringData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            var conversionError: NSError?
            var jsonDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableLeaves, error: &conversionError) as? NSDictionary
        })
        task.resume()
```

I need to find out how to make a proper signature and how I should encrypt it since its my fire time using such tools.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have a secret key hard-coded in your app - this negates its security. I'd suggest generating the key from your own server (eg using the excellent S3Direct django module), then obtain the key like this:

```
let filename = "myfile.mp4"
let requestUrl = Constants.my_own_server+"/s3direct/get_upload_params/"


println("Uploading file of name ***" + filename + "***")

let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let authToken : String = defaults.stringForKey("token")!

let manager = Manager.sharedInstance
manager.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = [
"Authorization": "Token " + authToken
]

let parameters : [ String : AnyObject] = [
    "type": "video/mp4",
    "name": filename,
    "dest": "vids"
]

Alamofire.request(.POST, requestUrl, parameters: parameters).response(serializer: Request.JSONResponseSerializer(), completionHandler: { (request, response, object, error) -> Void in
    //println(object)
    //println(error)
    if (error == nil) {
        self.uploadFile(videoData!, parameters: object as! [ String : String], filename: filename)
    }
    else {
        print("Failed to sign file")
    }
})
```

Good luck - I have found this particular stack unusually painful to get working.